# How can I find a model's relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to, when given a particular model, return all the related models it is associated with.  For example:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bones
  belongs_to :master
end

d = Dog.first
d.associations #<== should return [Bone, Master]
```

Is there a way to do this already without having to roll my own?  Failing that, any suggestions for the best way to do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
Dog.reflect_on_all_associations
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#M001405

You wouldn't do this on an instance but on the model itself.