# Where to get a list of all ActiveRecord Relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm debugging and testing some models in a complex Rails application. This is using [Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree), so with all the Decorating and required gems, the model is dirtied and monkeypatched by everyone and their dog.

In the tests, I want to see if a certain has-and-belongs-to relation is there, and configured properly.

Where, or how, can I get a list of all the relations that were made available to this model?

Edit. Duplicate of [How can I find a model's relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259529/how-can-i-find-a-models-relationships)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Model.reflect_on_all_associations
```

Ex.  `Dog.reflect_on_all_associations`

Checkout the link here:

[How can I find a model's relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259529/how-can-i-find-a-models-relationships)